# Saving Multiple Data in the Database and Display it in One Row of a Table

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, many-to-many

I would like create **one post with multiple categories**, not only one category.

My problem is that when I add a new post with, for example 2 categories, it creates 2 same posts (with same data: id, title, etc) but with 2 different categories.

First of all, **I created 3 tables in the database**: `posts`, `categories` and `postcategories`(the pivot table).

[Screenshot of the database with 3 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj3Vt.png)

Secondly, I wrote the code logic to **save the data into the database** when I add a new post in `add_post.php`.

```
<?php

        if(isset($_POST['create_post'])){

                $post_title       = escape($_POST['post_title']);
                $post_author      = escape($_POST['post_author']);
                $post_category_id = $_POST['post_category'];
                $post_status      = escape($_POST['post_status']);

                $post_image = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
                $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];
                $data= explode('.', $post_image ); 
                $extension= end($data); 
                $post_image = time() . '.' . $extension;

                $post_tags        = escape($_POST['post_tags']);
                $post_content     = escape($_POST['post_content']);
                $post_date        = escape(date('d-m-y'));

                $post_image = time();
                move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../assets/img/blog/" . $post_image);

                if(!empty($_POST['post_category'])) {
                        $query = "INSERT INTO posts
                                (post_title, post_author, post_date, 
                                post_image, post_content, post_tags, post_status)
                                VALUES(?,?,CURDATE(),?,?,?,?)";

                $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',
                        $_POST['post_title'],
                        $_POST['post_author'],
                        $post_image,
                        $_POST['post_content'],
                        $_POST['post_tags'],
                        $_POST['post_status']);
                if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
                    $the_post_id = $connection->insert_id;
                }

                $sql = 'INSERT INTO postcategories (post_id, cat_id) VALUES(?,?)';
                $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

                foreach( $_POST['post_category'] as $cat_id){
                        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $the_post_id, $cat_id);
                        $stmt->execute();            
                }

                echo "<h4 class='bg-success text-center'>Post Created: <a href='../post.php?p_id={$the_post_id}'>View Post</a> or <a href='posts.php'>View All Posts</a></h4>";

                }
        }
?>
```

Finally, in `view_all_posts.php`, I **joined the 3 tables of the database with INNER JOIN**, then **I looped through the data to display the created posts with the data and multiple categories for each post if I select more than one category**.

```
<?php

        $query = "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_title, posts.post_status,posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, ";
        $query .= "posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title, postcategories.post_id, postcategories.cat_id ";
        $query .= "FROM postcategories ";
        $query .= "INNER JOIN categories USING (cat_id) ";
        $query .= "INNER JOIN posts USING (post_id) "; 
        $query .= "ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC";

        $select_posts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts)){
                $post_id            = escape($row['post_id']);
                $post_author        = escape($row['post_author']);
                $post_title         = escape($row['post_title']);
                // $post_category_id   = escape($row['post_category_id']);
                $post_status        = escape($row['post_status']);
                $post_image         = escape($row['post_image']);
                $post_tags          = escape($row['post_tags']);
                $post_comment_count = escape($row['post_comment_count']);
                $post_date          = escape($row['post_date']);
                $category_title     = escape($row['cat_title']);
                $category_id        = escape($row['cat_id']);

        echo "<tr>";
?>

<td><input class='checkBoxes' type='checkbox' name='checkBoxArray[]' value='<?php echo $post_id; ?>'></td>
  
<?php
        echo "<td>$post_id</td>";
        echo "<td>$post_author</td>";
        echo "<td>$post_title</td>";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM postcategories WHERE cat_id = {$category_id} && post_id = {$post_id} ";
        $select_categories_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_id)) {
        $category_id = escape($row['cat_id']);
  
        echo "<td>{$category_title}</td>";
  
        }

        echo "<td>$post_status</td>";
        echo "<td><img src='../assets/img/blog/$post_image' alt='$post_title' width=100px></td>";
        echo "<td>$post_tags</td>";
        echo "<td>$post_comment_count</td>";
        echo "<td>$post_date</td>";
        echo "<td><a class='btn btn-primary' href='../blog-details.php?p_id={$post_id}'>View Post</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a class='btn btn-info' href='posts.php?source=edit_post&p_id={$post_id}'>Edit</a></td>";
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">

<?php
        echo "<td><input class='btn btn-danger' type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');\"></td>";
?>
</form>

<?php
        echo "</tr>";
        }
?>
```

I was expecting to display one post with multiple categories. However, it displays the same post several times depending on the number of categories I selected in the form.

[Screenshot of the posts in my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvcsT.png)

Comment: Show a brief set of input data, plus the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join these tables. When you do it, you duplicate the entries from the master table by the times the detail table entries. Example: 1 entry in the master table, 3 entries in the detail table for that master, so, if you join then, your master will display 3 times (1 for each detail).

So, what you need to do is:

1. Query your master table (post)
2. For each post you queried in the previous step, query their details (categories)

I don't use PHP for a long time, so I hope you understand what you should do from my sample code bellow, even if it has errors:

```php
// First, query posts
$postsQuery = 'SELECT post_id, post_author, post_title, post_status, post_image, post_tags, post_comment_count, post_date ';
$postsQuery .= 'from posts order by post_id ';
$postsQuery .= 'order by post_id';

$postsQryRes = mysqli_query($postsQuery);

while ($row = $postsQryRes->fetch_assoc()) {
  // Then, for each post, query its categories data
  $postCategoriesQuery = 'select categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title, postcategories.post_id, postcategories.cat_id ';
  $postCategoriesQuery .= 'from postcategories ';
  $postCategoriesQuery .= 'inner join categories USING (cat_id) ';
  $postCategoriesQuery .= 'where postcategories.post_id = ?';

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($postCategoriesQuery);
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $row['post_id']);
  $stmt->execute();

  // Then, join the categories using comma
  $catQryRes = $stmt->get_result();
  $categories = '';
  while ($row = $catQryRes->fetch_assoc()) {
    $categories .= $row['cat_title'] . ',';
  }

  // Now, you have the categories separated by comma in $categories.
  // Does the rest of the code.
  // Example:
  echo "<td>".$row['post_title']."</td>
       <td>".$categories."</td>";
 
}
```

**CORRECTION**
Well, you can join the tables, but, if you do it, you should implement an algorithm that deduplicates each post. The way I showed you above is a simpler one.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what I should do from your sample code above. Could you write the correct code related to my code and not a sample? If not, show me the algorithm that deduplicates each post.